# Runes Library Javascript

Tags: javascript, emoji

Quick question, I am sorting some notes and whenever i want to sort the notes for their tooltips which start with emoji i get a problem (Cause .substr(0,1) gives me ? (emojis take 2 ). so since i want to keep tooltip for "HELLO" - as H. For emoji i need to use .substr(0,2) but then all other notes have 2 Chars eg. Hello is HE.

However i discovered runes https://www.npmjs.com/package/runes

So now problem is i dont want to be repetitive and run every note throught runes.substr("MY MANY NOTES",1) i want to make a variable runner.

Example

```
var str = "Hello world!";
var res = str.substr(0,1);
```

As you can see JS just says **str**.substr, my question is how i can do str.runes.substr or any other way to achieve the same thing. Thanks in advance!

```
var runes = require("runes")    
var tooltip = 'sdas dsa'
tooltip.runes.substr(0, 1);
```

Comment: `runes.substr(tooltip, 1)` maybe? That's the example that's right there in the page you linked to.

Comment: yeah, my mind blocked totaly, went for a smoke and realized the same thing. still thank you 4 your time

Answer (score 0):

runes.substr(tooltip, 0,1)   - would be a solution

Answer (score 0):

First, I'll answer your question, **but please read the warning near the bottom**.

You can technically do `String.prototype.func = someFunc` to make it available in your strings:

```js
String.prototype.reverseAndCaps = function () { return `${this}`.split('').reverse().join('').toUpperCase() };

console.log("hello".reverseAndCaps());
```

Inside functions like that, you use `this` to refer to the string (you generally need to cast it as a string to get the primitive form).

So, for your `runes`, you could do something like:

```js
Object.assign(String.prototype, { runes: function() { 
  // replace this object with `runes` itself
  return {
    substr: (...args) => this.substr.apply(this, args)
  }; 
} });

console.log("hello".runes().substr(0, 2));
```

Note that `runes()` needs to be wrapped in a function in order to properly bind "this". There are other approaches you could use to not have to do it this way, but they'd have to be applied to every string.

All that said, it is **highly** recommended that you **do NOT do this**. Changing primitives can cause all kinds of unexpected side effects, and make your code more difficult to maintain because you have all sorts of magical extra things that might not be obvious where they come from.

Not to mention, saying `runes.substr(str, 0, 1)` isn't any shorter than `str.runes.substr(0, 1)`.